# Deficiency of unit eigenvalues in a stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

**Statement**

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be a (row) stochastic matrix. 
It is known that the eigenvalues of such matrix lies in the complex unit disk.

Now I am only interested in the eigenvalues that lies on the complex unit circle: $\lvert  \lambda \rvert = 1.$

**Does its geometric multiplicity $\gamma_A(\lambda)$ equal its algebraic multiplicity $\mu_A(\lambda)$?:**
$$
\lvert \lambda \rvert =1 \implies  \gamma_A(\lambda)=\mu_A(\lambda)  \quad ?
$$

---

**Context**

Let $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$ 
I am interested in the following limit:
$$
R=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k u
$$

I suspect that such limit must exists, as such equation appeared to me in the calculation of the average time reward of some markov reward process.

**Reduction**

- Let $A=PJP^{-1}$ the Jordan normal form of $A,$ and without a loss of generality, we will order the jordan blocks $J_{k}$ in decreasing order of the eigenvalue norms $\lvert \lambda_k \rvert$.
- Let $s_k$ be the size of the jordan block $J_k$

Now we analyse the convergence of a jordan block $J_k$ case by case:

1. If $\lvert \lambda_k \rvert < 1,$ then:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} J_k^r&=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n} (I_{s_k}-J_k^n)\times (I_{s_k}-J_k)^{-1} \\
   &= \mathbf{0}
   \end{align*}
   $$
2. If $\lvert \lambda_k \rvert = 1$ and $s_k=1,$ then $J_k$ is a scalar and:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} J_k^r&=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\lambda_k^r  \\
   &= \begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if}\space \lambda_k=1 \\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
   $$
3. Otherwise, if $\lvert \lambda_k\rvert=1$ and $s_k>1,$ I can prove that the limit **does not exist.**

Now, if I am not mistaken, my question is exactly that the case $3$ cannot occur.

Comment: The following may help: the matrix $R_n={1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k$ satisfies  $$(I-A)R_n=R_n(I-A)={1\over n} (I-A^n)\to 0$$

Comment: @math54321 the matrix you have proposed is not stochastic as it contains a negative entry: -1

Comment: My mistake - I forgot the entries should be nonnegative. In that case the desired result should follow from the Perron-Frobenius theorem and the [normal form for a reducible matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}A^k\ $ always converges as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ is a consequence of the structure of finite time-homogeneous Markov chains. The states of such a chain can always be partitioned into:

- A (possibly empty) set of [transient states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Markov_chain#Transience_and_recurrence);
- A positive finite number of non-empty [communication classes](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eww2040/4701Sum07/4701-06-Notes-MCII.pdf) of states.

The matrix $\ A\ $ then has the form
$$
A=U^{-1}\pmatrix{A_1&0_{n_1\times n_2}&\dots&0_{n_1\times n_c}&0_{n_1\times t}\\
0_{n_2\times n_1}&A_2&\dots&0_{n_2\times n_c}&0_{n_2\times t}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0_{n_c\times n_1}&0_{n_c\times n_2}&\dots&A_c&0_{n_c\times t}\\
T_1&T_2&\dots&T_c&T_{c+1}}U\ ,
$$
for some suitable permutation matrix $\ U\ $, where $\ t\ $ is the number of transient states, $\ c\ $ the number of communication classes, $\ n_i\ $ the number of states in the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ communication class, each $\ A_i\ $ is an $\ n_i\times n_i\ $ [irreducible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html) (row) stochastic matrix, $\ T_{c+1}\ $ is a $\ t\times t\ $matrix, some positive integral power of which has all its row sums strictly  less than $\ 1\ $, and
$$
A^n=U^{-1}\pmatrix{A_1^n&0_{n_1\times n_2}&\dots&0_{n_1\times n_c}&0_{n_1\times t}\\
0_{n_2\times n_1}&A_2^n&\dots&0_{n_2\times n_c}&0_{n_2\times t}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0_{n_c\times n_1}&0_{n_c\times n_2}&\dots&A_c^n&0_{n_c\times t}\\
X_{1n}&X_{2n}&\dots&X_{cn}&T_{c+1}^n}U
$$
for $\ n\ge1\ $, where $\ X_{in}=\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}T_{c+1}^kT_iA_i^{n-1-k}\ $. Because the row sums of  $\ T_{c+1}^r\ $ are strictly less than $\ 1\ $ for some positive $\ r\ $, $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}T_{c+1}^n=$$\,0_{t\times t}\ .$  If the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ communication class is [aperiodic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Markov_chains#Discrete_Time_Markov_Chains), then $\ A_i\ $ is [primitive](https://planetmath.org/primitivematrix),
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_i^n=\mathbf{1}_{n_i\times1}\pi_i^T\ ,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{in}=\big(I_{t\times t}-T_{c+1}\big)^{-1}T_i\mathbf{1}_{n_i\times1}\pi_i^T
$$
where $\ \pi_i^T\ $ is the (unique) stationary distribution of the Markov chain with transition matrix $\ A_i\ $ (satisfying the equation $\ \pi_i^TA_i=\pi_i^T\ $).  *A fortiori*, we therefore have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T_{c+1}^k&=0_{t\times t}\ ,\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_i^k&=\mathbf{1}_{n_i\times1}\pi_i^T\ \ \text{, and}\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_{ik}&=\big(I_{t\times t}-T_{c+1}\big)^{-1}T_i\mathbf{1}_{n_i\times1}\pi_i^T
\end{align}
If the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ communication class is periodic with period $\ d\ $, then it can be partitioned into $\ d\ $ sets $\ \mathscr{S}_0,$$\,\mathscr{S}_1,$$\,\dots,$$\,\mathscr{S}_{d-1}\ $ of states such that if the chain ever enters a state in one of the sets $\ \mathscr{S}_j\ $, it will thereafter cycle through states in the sets $\ \mathscr{S}_{j+1},$$\,\mathscr{S}_{j+2},$$\,\dots$$\,\mathscr{S}_{d-1},$
$\,\mathscr{S}_0,$$\,\mathscr{S}_1,$$\,\dots,$$\,\mathscr{S}_{j-1},$$\,\mathscr{S}_j\ $ in that order.  In this case, we can choose the matrix $\ U\ $ so  that $\ A_i\ $ has the form
$$
A_i=\pmatrix{0_{c_0\times c_0}&V_0&0_{c_0\times c_2}&\dots&0_{c_0\times c_{d-1}}\\
0_{c_1\times c_0}&0_{c_1\times c_1}&V_1&\dots&0_{c_1\times c_{d-1}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{c_{d-2}\times c_0}&0_{c_{d-2}\times c_1}& 0_{c_{d-2}\times c_2}&\dots&V_{d-2}\\
V_{d-1}&0_{c_{d-1}\times c_1}& 0_{c_{d-1}\times c_3}&\dots&0_{c_{d-1}\times c_{d-1}}}\ ,
$$
where $\ c_j=\big|\mathscr{S}_j\big|\ $.  The matrix $\ V_j\ $ is a $\ c_j\times c_{j+1\pmod{d}}\ $ stochastic matrix whose rows and columns are indexed by the states in $\ \mathscr{S}_j\ $ and $\ \mathscr{S}_{j+1\pmod{d}}\ $ respectively.  Although $\ A_i^n\ $ *doesn't* converge as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ in this case, it's neverthelesss still true that $\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}A_i^k\ $ *does* converge.

First, note that
$$
A_i^d=\pmatrix{W_0&0_{c_0\times c_1}&\dots&0_{c_0\times c_{d-1}}\\
0_{c_1\times c_0}&W_1&\dots&0_{c_1\times c_{d-1}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{c_{d-1}\times c_0}&0_{c_{d-1}\times c_1}&\dots&W_{d-1}}\ ,
$$
where $\ W_j\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\prod_\limits{k=0}^{d-1}V_{j+k\pmod{ d}}\ $ is a primitive $\ c_j\times c_j\ $ matrix.  Therefore ,
\begin{align}
A_i^{rd}&=\pmatrix{W_0^r&0_{c_0\times c_1}&\dots&0_{c_0\times c_{d-1}}\\
0_{c_1\times c_0}&W_1^r&\dots&0_{c_1\times c_{d-1}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{c_{d-1}\times c_0}&0_{c_{d-1}\times c_1}&\dots&W_{d-1}^r}\\
&\rightarrow\pmatrix{\mathbf{1}_{c_0\times1}\omega_0^T&0_{c_0\times c_1}&\dots&0_{c_0\times c_{d-1}}\\
0_{c_1\times c_0}&\mathbf{1}_{c_1\times1}\omega_1^T&\dots&0_{c_1\times c_{d-1}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{c_{d-1}\times c_0}&0_{c_{d-1}\times c_1}&\dots&\mathbf{1}_{c_{d-1}\times1}\omega_{d-1}^T}
\end{align}
as $\ r\rightarrow\infty\ $, where $\ \omega_j^T\ $ is the unique stationary distribution of the Markov chain with transition matrix $\ W_j\ $. It's then not difficult to show that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_i^k=\frac{1}{d}\pmatrix{\mathbf{1}_{c_0\times1}\\\mathbf{1}_{c_1\times1}\\\vdots\\\mathbf{1}_{c_{d-1}\times1}}\pmatrix{\omega_0^T&\omega_1^T&\dots&\omega_{d-1}^T}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_{ik}\\
&=\frac{1}{d}\big(I_{t\times t}-T_{c+1}\big)^{-1}T_i\pmatrix{\mathbf{1}_{c_0\times1}\\\mathbf{1}_{c_1\times1}\\\vdots\\\mathbf{1}_{c_{d-1}\times1}}\pmatrix{\omega_0^T&\omega_1^T&\dots&\omega_{d-1}^T}
\end{align}

Therefore, now let $\ B_i\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}A_i^k\ $ and $\ 
Y_i\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}X_{ik}\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots,c\ $.  Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k\\
&=U^{-1}\pmatrix{B_1&0_{n_1\times n_2}&\dots&0_{n_1\times n_c}&0_{n_1\times t}\\
0_{n_2\times n_1}&B_2&\dots&0_{n_2\times n_c}&0_{n_2\times t}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0_{n_c\times n_1}&0_{n_c\times n_2}&\dots&B_c&0_{n_c\times t}\\
Y_1&Y_2&\dots&Y_c&0_{t\times t}}U\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I took some time to review your answer, but it seems solid and correct. And it does give a construction for that limit.

Some notes I have, you used the term "strictly sub-stochastic". I had to guess its meaning: A matrix $T$ where $\sum_{j}T_{i,j} < 1.$ Can you give a reference to its definition?

Also, you have used the property $i\le c\implies T_{i}T_{c+1}=0,$ while I found it true by construction, I think it is best to explicitly say it to a reader who is not expert in Markov Chains.

Otherwise, you answer is excellent!, and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for reading the answer so carefully.  You've managed to home in on what are hopefully its only two significant errors.  First, it's not necessarily true that $\ T_{c+1}\ $ is strictly substochastic, although some positive integral power of it must be.  It turns out, however, that the term "strictly substochastic" is ambiguous anyway.

Comment: Some authors use it to mean the same thing that I've always considered it to mean (which you've guessed correctly).   It seems to be more commonly used, however, to mean the weaker property of being substochastic, but not stochastic.  In view of this ambiguity, however, I've modified my answer to avoid any use of the term.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are a few papers that do use it with the same meaning that I do: [1, p.40](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA108336.pdf), [2,p.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01763.pdf), [3, p.159](https://jmmrc.uk.ac.ir/article_3147_7669b32a3aa572846155f8686997c8a2.pdf), [4, p.43](https://escholarship.org/content/qt9k39475h/qt9k39475h_noSplash_d39c9d070bb12c227e4124f31ce7086c.pdf).  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221664/a-property-of-matrix-i-a-1-for-a-strictly-substochastic) MathStackExchange question also uses it with this same sense

Comment: The second error is in the form of the matrix $\ A^n\ $.  I didn't get the last last row of the expression I gave for this because $\ T_{c+1}T_i=0\ $ (which isn't necessarily true in general), but because I blundered in the matrix multiplication.  Hopefully, the amended answer is now correct.  I've checked that the amended formulas work on a $\ 12$-state Markov chain with $\ 3\ $ transient states, one $\ 3$-periodic communicating class with $\ 9\ $ states, and one aperiodic communicating class with $\ 3\ $ states.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, as we assume that all the entries of $A$ are positive, or more generally $A$ is irreducible.

By the Perron-Frobenius theorem the space $\ker(I-A)$ is one dimensional and consists of the multiples of the eigevector  $(1,1,\ldots, 1)^T.$ By the same theorem the space $\ker(I-A^T)$ is one dimensional, hence ${\rm Im}(I-A)$ has dimension $n-1.$

We can treat the matrix $A$ as the operator $A:\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n).$ The matrix is row stochastic therefore $\|A\|=1.$ Hence $\|A^n\|=1$ for any $n.$ Let $$R_n={1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k$$ Then $\|R_n\|=1$ and  $$(I-A)R_n=R_n(I-A)={1\over n}(I-A^n)\underset{n}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ As the sequence $R_n$ is bounded, every subsequence of $R_n$ contains a convergent subsequence $R_{n_k}.$ Let $P=\lim_k R_{n_k}.$ Then $$P(I-A)=(I-A)P=0$$ Hence $P$ vanishes on ${\rm Im}(I-A)$ and ${\rm Im}P\subset \ker (I-A).$ For $u\in \ker (I-A)$ we have $R_nu=u,$ hence $Pu=u.$ Therefore ${\rm Im}P= \ker (I-A).$ The intersection of $\ker(I-A)$ and ${\rm Im}(I-A)$ is trivial. Indeed, assume by contradiction that
$$(I-A)v=(1,1,\ldots, 1)^T$$ Let $v_k$ be the smallest coordinate of $v.$ We have
$$1=v_k-\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}v_j\le v_k-\left (\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}\right )v_k=0$$
We obtained a contradiction. Hence
$$\mathbb{R}^n={\rm Im}(I-A)\oplus \ker (I-A)$$ The operator $P$ vanishes on the first subspace and acts as identity on the second space.

Summarizing every subsequence of $R_n$ contains a subsequence convergent to $P.$ Thus the whole sequence is convergent to $P.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 


But doesn't Perron–Frobenius theorem seals the deal immediately for positive stochastic matrices?

From the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices

It says that the leading eigenvalue is simple, which should constitute a direct proof for positive stochastic matrices.

Still, great job! it does answer the question for the more general irreducible matrices.

Comment: Also, to understand the final step correctly. You are arguing that the set of accumulation points for the sequence $(R_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the singleton $\{P\}.$ Thus the sequence converges to $P$?

Comment: If every subsequence of $R_n$ contains a subsequence convergent to $P$ then the sequence $R_n$ is convergent to $P.$ Indeed if $R_n$ is not convergent to $P,$ then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\| R_n-P\|\ge \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n,$ i.e. there is a subsequence $R_{n_k}-P\|\ge \varepsilon.$ But the subsequence $R_{n_k}$ contains a subsequence convergent to $P,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very short proof to OP's question about semi-simplicity of eigenvalues on the unit circle for stochastic matrix $A$.  OP considered using Jordan Normal Form, so let $J=P^{-1}AP$ and suppose that $\lambda_i \in S^1$ is not semi-simple. Then letting $M:=\Big\Vert P^{-1}\big\Vert_F\cdot\big \Vert P\big\Vert_F$

$k \leq \Big\Vert J_i^k\big\Vert_F\leq \Big\Vert J^k\big\Vert_F=\Big\Vert P^{-1}A^kP\big\Vert_F\leq M \cdot \Big\Vert A^k\big\Vert_F$
$ = M\cdot \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m (a_{i,j}^{(k)}})^2\leq M\cdot \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m a_{i,j}^{(k)}=M\cdot \mathbf 1^T\big(A^k\mathbf 1\big) = M\cdot m$
by direct calculation, submultiplicativity of the Frobenius norm and triangle inequality.  Observe that the upper bound is constant but the lower bound may be made arbitrarily large, which is a contradiction. Conclude $\lambda_i$ is semi-simple.

**Remark:** if we first decompose $A$ into irreducibles, we can do this with less machinery than JNF -- e.g. Schur Triangularization and a little cleverness is enough.